# Giving variables and constraints in exported lp files useful names?

Tags: pyomo

In pyomo, when I export models to LP files with `model.write()`, all variables are named `x_<index>`. Constraints have similarly generic names. How do I set these names?

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `model.write(symbolic_solver_labels=True)`. This will likely take longer than the alternative, but it should give you clearer names.

You are also able to specify your own symbol labeler, but that is not yet a well-documented capability.